# JavaScript V8 создание и использование скрытых классов

Tags: javascript, v8

Всем привет! Возник вопрос по поводу работы V8. Вот предположим мы создали объект какой-то и для него создалась цепочка скрытых классов. Правильно ли я понимаю, что всю необходимую информацию для работы с объектом уже будет содержать последний скрытый класс и предыдущая цепочка скрытых классов нам нужна просто для того, чтобы при наличии похожих объектов у них создавались одинаковые скрытые классы, что позволяло бы производить дополнительную оптимизацию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам вопрос задал, сам на него и нашел ответ. 
Когда идет работа с объектом (например чтение какого-то свойства из него), то сначала мы обратимся к последнему скрытому классу и если в нем не будет находиться нужное нам свойство (каждый элемент в цепочке скрытых классов хранит в себе только одно свойство, которое мы задали), то мы обратимся к словарю этой цепочки, который хранит информацию о том, в каком скрытом классе в цепочке - находится нужное нам свойство и мы сможем к нему перейти. Скрытый класс не хранит все предыдущие свойства с целью экономии памяти. Такая цепочка скрытых классов даст нам возможность понять, что два разных объекта могут относиться к одному и тому же скрытому классу, а это в свою очередь даст нам возможность воспользоваться **инлайн кэшами**.

Инлайн кэши - это отдельная тема. Тут нам придется заглянуть в байткод. Если мы его прочитаем, то при получении какого-то свойства из объекта - будет вызвана соответствующая инструкция. Встроенный в эту инструкцию инлайн кэш запоминает то, к какой цепочке относится объект, у которого мы искали нужное нам свойство и запоминает смещение этого свойства. Если в будущем мы захотим у другого объекта, который относится к той же цепочки скрытого класса получить такое же свойство, то инструкция посмотрит в инлайн кэш и увидит, что значение этого свойства хранится по такому-то смещению и мы сможем быстро получить к нему доступ. Все этим оптимизации довольно сильно ускоряют javascript